# Split the column value having "|" delimiter and again split the "~" to three different columns (A,B,C) in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to split the below data in a pyspark dataframe column "G_Codes" first with | delimiter and then convert each split value having the ~ delimiter to three new columns.

The | delimiter values are not fixed, some have 3 or 2 and some have 4 or 5.But the ~ delimiter values are fixed of 3.

### Sample Rows:

```
020~Panel~RI|003~analysis, Complete~UR|004~Insert~RI|009~With Differential/Plate~HE|0850~Vitin , 25-Hydrogen~RI|2210~ Panel w/ Ratio~AC|3012~Comp.Panel (14)~AC|5270~globe A1c~AC

0017~Acid~AC|001362~Kine,Total~AC|0053~A1c~AC|0072~analysis, Complete~UR|0459~TSH~RI|022~No Differential~HE|375~Panel~AC|3220~Comp. Panel (1)~AC

0567~CM78+9AC~GN|303756~Panel~AC

0009~ With Differential~HE|3756~Panel~AC|3220~Comp. Panel (1)~AC

001974~Free, Direct~RI|004259~Lghj~RI

0008~Panel~RI|003772~analysis, Complete~UR|0059~ With Differential~HE|102525~Estimation~AC|1285~Ratio,Shgc~AC|2350~Huik Ratio~GN|334~Copy18+eyR~AC
```

I tried different split options but didn't work, Need your expertise help here to achieve below output. Thanks.

Expected Output for above first row:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyH3j.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I just realized that you wanted a PySpark dataframe and not a Pandas dataframe. I guess the dictionary "D" obtained towards the end of the code below can be used for further operations.

First split the data based on `|` and store it in a list, as you might have already done.

```py
import pandas as pd

sample_data = "020~Panel~RI|003~analysis, Complete~UR|004~Insert~RI|009~With Differential/Plate~HE|0850~Vitin , 25-Hydrogen~RI|2210~ Panel w/ Ratio~AC|3012~Comp.Panel (14)~AC|5270~globe A1c~AC"

L = sample_data.split("|")
```

Then iterate through the list and split each row into three parts using `~` as the delimiter and generate a dictionary with keys as 'A', 'B', 'C' (header values) and values as list of items in each row of the expected dataframe.

```py
D = {'A':[],
     'B':[],
     'C':[]}

for row in L:
    a,b,c = row.split("~")

    D['A'] += [a]
    D['B'] += [b]
    D['C'] += [c]

df = pd.DataFrame(D)
```

Output (in IDLE Shell):

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(D)
      A                        B   C
0   020                    Panel  RI
1   003       analysis, Complete  UR
2   004                   Insert  RI
3   009  With Differential/Plate  HE
4  0850      Vitin , 25-Hydrogen  RI
5  2210           Panel w/ Ratio  AC
6  3012          Comp.Panel (14)  AC
7  5270                globe A1c  AC
```

Comment: Thanks @MJK for the inputs, Yes i am looking for pyspark dataframe dynamic code to convert all the rows in a dataframe column. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to do is to split by `|`, and then explode to get one record per row. Once we have one record per row, we can use `spark.read.csv` to parse it as a CSV file.

```py
>>> df = spark.read.text("rows.txt")
>>> # Regex used in F.split(). We have to scape the | character
>>> regex = "\|"
>>> rows_df = df.select(F.explode(F.split("value", regex)).alias("value"))
>>> # Before parsing as CSV, it's important to select only the value (Otherwise we'd parse a pyspark.sql.Row)
>>> rows_rdd = rows_df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.value)
>>> # Once we have an RDD with all rows, we can parse as CSV
>>> spark.read.csv(rows_rdd, inferSchema=True, sep="~").show()
>>> # I didn't use an schema, but you can use one
+------+--------------------+---+
|   _c0|                 _c1|_c2|
+------+--------------------+---+
|    20|               Panel| RI|
|     3|  analysis, Complete| UR|
|     4|              Insert| RI|
|     9|With Differential...| HE|
|   850| Vitin , 25-Hydrogen| RI|
|  2210|      Panel w/ Ratio| AC|
|  3012|     Comp.Panel (14)| AC|
|  5270|           globe A1c| AC|
|    17|                Acid| AC|
|  1362|          Kine,Total| AC|
|    53|                 A1c| AC|
|    72|  analysis, Complete| UR|
|   459|                 TSH| RI|
|    22|     No Differential| HE|
|   375|               Panel| AC|
|  3220|     Comp. Panel (1)| AC|
|   567|            CM78+9AC| GN|
|303756|               Panel| AC|
|     9|   With Differential| HE|
|  3756|               Panel| AC|
+------+--------------------+---+
```

Note the line `rows_rdd = rows_df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.value)`. This is what happens if you don't put it:

```
>>> df = spark.read.text("rows.txt")
>>> # Regex used in F.split(). We have to scape the | character
>>> regex = "\|"
>>> rows_df = df.select(F.explode(F.split("value", regex)).alias("value"))
>>> spark.read.csv(rows_df.rdd, inferSchema=True, sep="~").show()
+-----------------+--------------------+----+
|              _c0|                 _c1| _c2|
+-----------------+--------------------+----+
|   Row(value='020|               Panel|RI')|
|   Row(value='003|  analysis, Complete|UR')|
|   Row(value='004|              Insert|RI')|
|   Row(value='009|With Differential...|HE')|
|  Row(value='0850| Vitin , 25-Hydrogen|RI')|
|  Row(value='2210|      Panel w/ Ratio|AC')|
|  Row(value='3012|     Comp.Panel (14)|AC')|
|  Row(value='5270|           globe A1c|AC')|
|  Row(value='0017|                Acid|AC')|
|Row(value='001362|          Kine,Total|AC')|
|  Row(value='0053|                 A1c|AC')|
|  Row(value='0072|  analysis, Complete|UR')|
|  Row(value='0459|                 TSH|RI')|
|   Row(value='022|     No Differential|HE')|
|   Row(value='375|               Panel|AC')|
|  Row(value='3220|     Comp. Panel (1)|AC')|
|  Row(value='0567|            CM78+9AC|GN')|
|Row(value='303756|               Panel|AC')|
|  Row(value='0009|   With Differential|HE')|
|  Row(value='3756|               Panel|AC')|
+-----------------+--------------------+----+
```

As you see an ugly `Row(value='` and `')` are added. This happens because internally a `Dataframe` is no more than a `Dataset` of `Rows`. That's what we avoid with `rows_rdd = rows_df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.value)`.

Comment: cruzlorite much appreciated, your code works as expected..
But now i am facing different issue as below.
The "G_Codes" column comes from a table and here its splitted into three columns,Now I want to add these columns to the existing table where all the three columns are available in the table. Please advise on this.

Comment: Hi Mahesh! I don't fully understand your issue. I recommend you creating a new question detailing thoroughly your issue. If you do so, pass it. I'll try to help if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
spark
.read
.option("delimiter", "~")
.option("lineSep", "|")
.option("multiline", "true")
.csv(path)
.selectExpr(
        "CAST(_c0 AS INT) AS A",
         "_c1 AS B",
         "_c2 AS C"
    )
.show(false)
```

```
+------+-----------------------+------------+
|A     |B                      |C           |
+------+-----------------------+------------+
|20    |Panel                  |RI          |
|3     |analysis, Complete     |UR          |
|4     |Insert                 |RI          |
|9     |With Differential/Plate|HE          |
|850   |Vitin , 25-Hydrogen    |RI          |
|2210  | Panel w/ Ratio        |AC          |
|3012  |Comp.Panel (14)        |AC          |
|5270  |globe A1c              |AC\n\n0017  |
|1362  |Kine,Total             |AC          |
|53    |A1c                    |AC          |
|72    |analysis, Complete     |UR          |
|459   |TSH                    |RI          |
|22    |No Differential        |HE          |
|375   |Panel                  |AC          |
|3220  |Comp. Panel (1)        |AC\n\n0567  |
|303756|Panel                  |AC\n\n0009  |
|3756  |Panel                  |AC          |
|3220  |Comp. Panel (1)        |AC\n\n001974|
|4259  |Lghj                   |RI\n\n0008  |
|3772  |analysis, Complete     |UR          |
+------+-----------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Srinivas But i need to do it on top of dataframe but not on csv file, As my csv file has multiple columns and has to split on only one column, please share how i can achieve this..